# determining significance between counts in a chi square test?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I wish to know if there is a statistically significant difference between generational cohorts (Boomers, Gex X, Gen Y) using the frequency in which subjects selected a particular leadership quality as "important". For example, for subjects that selected the leadership quality "competence", I ran a cross-tabs analysis in SPSS (Generational Cohort by Competence) and received the observed and expected counts, the Pearson Chi-Sq Aysmp Sig (2-sided) result (.046), and Cramer's V value (.097).

However, this only tells me whether there is a difference across the cohorts, not where the differences lie (Boomers-Gen X, GenX-Gen Y, etc). Is there a test I can run that will take these observed counts for each of the three cohort groups generated by the cross-tabs test and tell me if there is a significant difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Can you ask SPSS to output the standardized residuals for each cell as an option?

If so, you can examine them to determine which to determine which cells' observed frequencies differ significantly from their expected frequencies. If alpha = .05, then you can look for values > or < 1.96, or SPSS may also output the significance values automatically.

That doesn't quite tell you which differ from one another, which might require a different approach, such as an ANOVA with post-hoc analyses.